# AngularJS & Firebase - Get specific values from database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularfire

Sorry to bother you with this, I have thoroughly searched for this but I have been actively trying to resolve this for over 20hrs. Im about to abandon working with angularjs and firebase.  Just cant get my head around it..

I am trying to add database values to the page from an array.  Its working for other data but not this.

My firebase database:
[image: Firebase]
I have included the freebets related code which is all good but the bookie deatils just wont work.  There is other bookie details in the array which I will call aswell just wanted to get one working..

```
  myApp.controller('BetsController',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

    //Values passed throu routeparams are assigned to variables and then used to search the firebase database.

  var ref, freeBetList, test;
  $scope.whichoffer = $routeParams.oId;
  $scope.whichuser = $routeParams.uId;

  ref = firebase.database().ref()
    .child('users').child($scope.whichuser)
    .child('offers').child($scope.whichoffer)
    .child('freeBets');

  freeBetList = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.freeBets = freeBetList;


  test = firebase.database().ref()
    .child('users').child($scope.whichuser)
    .child('offers');

//.child('offerbookie')
//  testing = $firebaseObject(test);
testing = $firebaseArray(test);
$scope.test = testing;
```

```
<div class="card meetings cf">
  <h2>Free Bets</h2>
  <div class="meeting" ng-repeat="(key, freeBets) in freeBets">
        <a href="#">
        <span class="text">{{freeBets.eventname}}</span>
      </a>
      <button class="btn btn-delete tooltip"
        ng-click="deleteOffer(key)"><span>Delete this offer</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card meetings cf">
      <h2>Offer Details</h2>
      <div class="meeting" ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
        <a href="#">
          <p>{{whichoffer.offerbookie}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Console.log:

```
[]
​
"$$added": function added()
​
"$$error": function error()
​
"$$getKey": function getKey()
​
"$$moved": function moved()
​
"$$notify": function notify()
​
"$$process": function process()
​
"$$removed": function removed()
​
"$$updated": function updated()
​
"$add": function add()
​
"$destroy": function destroy()
​
"$getRecord": function getRecord()
​
"$indexFor": function indexFor()
​
"$keyAt": function keyAt()
​
"$loaded": function loaded()
​
"$ref": function ref()
​
"$remove": remove()
​​
length: 1
​​
name: "bound $remove"
​​
__proto__: function ()
​
"$resolved": true
​
"$save": function save()
​
"$watch": function watch()
​
0: Object { date: 1529091671870, offerbookie: "Coral", offermarket: "Betfair", … }
​
1: Object { date: 1529150480309, offerbookie: "SkyBet", offermarket: "Smarkets", … }
​
length: 2
​
__proto__: Array []
bets.js:42:4
```

I just want to display the one offerbookie value relevent to `$scope.whichoffer`.

### Current output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what part of code not working? Can you do console.log(testing) after last line of controller code & post it here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - {{whichoffer.offerbookie}}  I have been tryring to get the value of offerbookie to display without success.

Comment: ReferenceError: testing is not defined[Learn More] bets.js:44:2

Comment: For that 1st initialize it. do like: var testing = $firebaseArray(test); $scope.test = testing; console.log(testing);

Comment: first of all define testing and then try.

Comment: Wasnt sure how to add the whole log:​
"$watch": function watch()
​
0: Object { date: 1529091671870, offerbookie: "Coral", offermarket: "Betfair", … }
​
1: Object { date: 1529150480309, offerbookie: "SkyBet", offermarket: "Smarkets", … }
​
length: 2
​
__proto__: Array []

Comment: What do you get when you do a console.log of `$scope.whichoffer`? My guess is that it is a primative; not an object.

Comment: Hi George - it reads - -LF3xoQ389LGEuSOVOWb which is one of the autogenerated keys?  I think your right.  I will research objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show bookie details of your `ref` then, save $firebaseArray value directly into scope variable (instead of using another local var `testing`). edit your controller code to:

```
$scope.test = $firebaseArray(test);
```

And now after successful request it'll have array of two objects which you can show on DOM using ng-repeat as:

```
<div class="card meetings cf">
  <h2>Offer Details</h2>
  <div class="meeting" ng-repeat="bookie in test | filter: {'$id' : whichoffer}">
    <a href="#">
      <p>{{bookie.offerbookie}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I've changed ng-repeat expression. The one which you've used is for looping over  object properties not an array.

Update:

Actually for this case you don't even need ng-repeat because it will always be one unique value. Although above code will work,  You can just use `.filter` method of pure JS on `$scope.test` after getting successful response & it'll also still work.

Comment: Thanks very much for the assistantce.  I have updated the current output image which now shows the value being presented from both offer trees in the database.  How can I get it to only present the one associated with the current Whichoffer variable?  I will investigate the .filter method. Thanks you!

Comment: @Matt Check my updated ng-repeat expression. It's along with filter which filters array based on $id property with value as whichoffer. This will also give you required result

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so so much! This had totaly stumped me!  Thank you again!

Comment: @Matt Welcome! If it works you can upvote/accept the answer ;)